# Adwords script - exclude campaign name

Tags: sql, google-ads-api

I've used this line to include campaign names that contains `"Test"` like this:

```
'WHERE CampaignName CONTAINS "Test" '
```

How can I exclude the campaign name?
I've tried `NOT CONTAINS` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all the campaigns that not contains "Test" you can use this:

```
WHERE CampaignName DOES_NOT_CONTAIN_IGNORE_CASE 'Test'
```

See the column Operators on https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/awql?hl=en

Comment: DOES_NOT_CONTAIN Works!

Comment: Yep! And you can add the ignore case if you want that... ;)